# MySQL-Join: Get entries of parent item where latest entry is older than 2 days

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

I got two tables with mails: One table contains the meta-information of an email-conversation like participants, title, ...

Conversations:

```
id - title
```

The second table contains the attached messages, which are joined via conversation-id:

Messages:

```
id - conversationid - date
```

Now I would like to get the id of all conversations where the last attached message is older than 2 days.

I created this:

```
SELECT max(c.date) as lastanswer, t.id
FROM daf64_bestia_mails as m
LEFT JOIN daf64_bestia_mails_messages AS c ON c.conversationid=t.conversationid
WHERE t.state = 0
```

Now if I try to get

```
AND lastanswer > 2015-07-19
```

I get an error that tells me, that lastanswer is not known.

How can I create a correct query here?

Comment: aggregate function without group by ? and alias cant be used in where it could be used as `having lastanswer > '2015-07-19'`

Comment: Hm, okay, so I can use

`SELECT max(c.date) as lastanswer, t.id
FROM daf64_bestia_mails as m
LEFT JOIN daf64_bestia_mails_messages AS c ON c.conversationid=t.conversationid
WHERE t.state = 0 
HAVING lastanswer > 2015-07.19
GROUP BY t.conversationid`

Unfortunately I get an syntax error at position "Group by" here...

Comment: Got it - HAVING has to be after the GROUP BY